# Visual Studio - Add reference and access denied

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to add a reference to a project in VS 2010, and getting the following error message:

```
The Add Reference Dialog could not be shown due to the error:

Access to the path 'C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Local\Temp' is denied.

The error details have been saved to C:\Users\<my_user_code>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ShowAddReferenceDialog.log
```

The log file doesn't help - it just shows the full stack trace for the above error. The part that is confusing is that VS is trying to access the \administrator profile, when I am not logged in as 'administrator', nor am an administrator on my machine.

This also happens irrespective of the project as well, so it occurs even for a brand new project.

Is there a workaround or fix for that so that I can change the temporary folder that Visual Studio is attempting to write to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out the problem. One of the references was installed into the Administrator\Temp folder (for some reason), and due to policy restrictions that were recently implemented in our DOMAIN, read access to this folder was removed.

We reinstalled the dependency, and all is good.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that come to mind are -

1) Run Visual Studio as administrator
2) MSConfig -> User Account Control settings, bottom out the slider to "no warnings" -> Restart

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, @Dave S. Are these suggestions to just suppress/hide the fact that VS is attempting to access a folder in the administrator's profile, or to allow VS to correct itself? Due to company policy, running VS as administrator is not an option, and we don't have access to MSConfig either (it needs administrator privileges to work).

Comment: Daniel, I believe the answer is yes to both. I recommend contacting whomever can assist by requesting the necessary permissions to troubleshoot or request they troubleshoot the problem themselves, as I would make the assumption the problem is beyond my permissible ability to troubleshoot or fix. In other words, I'd feel comfortable submitting a ticket for a problem I don't have the allowed means to troubleshoot.